# Show errormessage in AngularJS using a global errorhandler

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I'm creating an angular JS using a global error handler to catch all my ajax errors.
Using JQuery, I just append a div to the top of my body with the errorcontent.
In Angular, I can't find a way to do this in a proper way.
Using $scope gives me a module error.
This is the code I'm using (found it here on stackoverflow):

```
(function(){
  var httpInterceptor = function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $location) {
      return {
        response: function (response) {
          return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {           
          if(rejection.status === 401) {
        //show message not autorized
          }
          if(rejection.status === 500) {
            $location.path("/error");
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
  };
  angular.module("testApp").config(httpInterceptor);
}());
```

When getting a 500 error I redirect to an errorpage, which is fine, but when I encounter less critical errors, I just want to display them above my content, how can I achieve this without using JQuery and using full Angular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a flashmessage plugin I found here: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/angular-flash/

which is pretty lightweight and works great.